# Store very little Integer in DB( PostgreSQL )

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, optimization, django-rest-framework

How to store very little Integer (4 bits) integer in my database?

Hi.
In my model, I want to store a very small integer in my DB and I don't want to use SmallIntegerField.
 Because Django will store 16 Byte data in DB, which is too much for my need. How can I store 4 bits integers or even less in PostgreSQL? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Huh. Per [Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#integerfield) `SmallIntegerField` is `Values from -32768 to 32767 ...` which is 2 bytes storage. `IntegerField` is 4 bytes.

Comment: I want to store smaller integers. The maximum of my needs is 32.

Comment: You are specifying two different things here, storage size and maximum value. I don't see anyway you get the storage down to 4 bits. You can constrain the maximum value with a `CHECK`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adrian said, the smallest storage for PostgreSQL itself is 2 bytes. There is nothing smaller than that.

If you want to make a constraint, create a maximum check via the `save` method in a Django model or add a field validator in the Django field.

2 bytes is the smallest, but there is nothing else

If you really want a database with such constraints, you can install an extension and make your own DB field by following this:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159090/how-to-store-one-byte-integer-in-postgresql